# How do I rotate a Paragraph in reportlab in SimpleDoc Template

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I have this reportlab pdf generator app I am building and I am using SimpleDocTemplate as my page template. I cannot seem to be able to rotate a Paragraph by 90 degrees as intented. Does anyone have a solution to this?

```
#----
    file_number1 = f"<font name='Helvetica' size='11'><b>{parcel.FileNumber}</b></font>"
    file_number1_style = styles['BodyText_FileNumber']
    file_number1_style.leftIndent = -320           
    file_number1_data = Paragraph(file_number1, file_number1_style)
    elements.append(file_number1_data)
    elements.append(Spacer(1, -5))            
#----
```

There is no rotate attribute on Paragraph. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer

def rotate_text(canvas):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.rotate(90)
    ptext = "Rotated Text"
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    p = Paragraph(ptext, styles['BodyText'])
    p.wrapOn(canvas, 100, 500)
    p.drawOn(canvas, -100, 0)
    canvas.restoreState()

def generate_pdf():
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("rotate_text.pdf", pagesize=letter)
    elements = []

    c = canvas.Canvas("rotate_text.pdf", pagesize=letter)
    rotate_text(c)
    c.showPage()
    c.save()

generate_pdf()
```

Comment: Thanks @MahmoodN 
I have followed this flow but it still does not show on the pdf.